# Optional logging to txt file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am logging to txt file like this:

```
with open('volumes.txt', 'a') as out:
            out.write('something1\n')
            somefunctuion(someparams, out)



def somefunction(self, someparams, out):
    out.write('something2\n')
    anotherfunction(anotherparams, out)

def anotherfunction(self, anotherparams, out):
    out.write('something3\n')
    otherotherfunction(params, out)
```

volumes.txt:

```
something1 
something2 
something3
 .... etc
```

As you can see, I have several nested functions and they all log to one file using `out.write()` method, this log file I pass as parameter. I feel like my architecture is not as good as wanted it to be. But right now I don't have time for refactoring, I need just a hot fix:
I need some flag to enable or disable logging.

How can I do this, without using `if loggerOnFlag: out.write()` construction every time? ( I will have tooo many ifs otherwise)

Comment: You can create a wrapper through the file handle.

Comment: Do proper logging by using the `logging` module, then you can have 2 streamhandlers, one standard output stream the other one can be a file.

Comment: You can conditionally open [`os.devnull`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.devnull) as a stopgap. However, as @user1767754 suggested, I would suggest looking at [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html).

Comment: @Galen can you show me an example of os.devnull?

Comment: @Galen I guess I got it: I just set file name to ''/dev/null'

Comment: @user2950593 Look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.devnull). Use `os.devnull` as the path. It will be more portable.